# Elegant way to remove every instance of a key in an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object and I want to copy this object and remove every instance of `description` from it. What is an elegant way of doing this?
here's how the object looks:

```
{
  properties: {
    a: {
      value: foo,
      description: bar
    },
    b: {
      value: foo,
      description: bar
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code you've used to remove the keys?

Comment: I tried looping through every single object in properties and removing description from it

Comment: If `foo` and `bar` are primitives then you could use JSON to stringify and then parse with a reviver. This would give you a copy with `description` removed. If they are complex object then this method would not work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the second argument to `JSON.parse`:

```
const output = JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify(input), 
  (key, value) => key === "description" ? undefined : value
);
```

A return value of `undefined` from this function tells `JSON.parse` to skip it.